# Enabling multi-touch settings?

Tags: multi-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable Multitouch features on My Desktop Touch Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109078/how-can-i-enable-multitouch-features-on-my-desktop-touch-screen)

Is there any way to enable the touchscreen setting in ubuntu 11.10? 
Like hold to right-click, two finger to scroll

thanks (:

Comment: Is it a legit touchscreen, as in a tablet? Or is it just a touchpad, like that of a laptop?

Comment: srry, its a legit touchscreen