# How can I enable Multitouch features on My Desktop Touch Screen

Tags: 11.10, unity, hardware, multi-touch, touchscreen

I have a "Medion" Touchscreen (bought from Aldi). The display works perfectly, as do single touch inputs. However, despite the screen being multitouch capable, I can't get multitouch gestures to work. I've tried installing the "evtouch" package from the repository, but this has not solved the problem.

I'd like to get this to the point where I can understand the problem well enough to file a bug :)

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

first of all install utouch

```
sudo apt-get install utouch
```

I have a touchscreen computer too and I use "touchegg" for the gesture recognizer, it work great. Unfortunately, right now there aren't too much apps for ubuntu focused on touchscreen.
If you are interested in touchegg you can download it

```
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

and configure the .conf file placed "/home/"user"/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf